# Run a python project cloned with git

Tags: python, git, batch-file

I have a python project shared with git. This project needs 50 packages. To run this project I have installed these packages on my virtual environment. How to allow an other machine to run the project ? Need I create a .bat file to create a venv , install the 50 packages on the venv and run the app?

There is an easier way to run the project on another machine ?
I am beginning, I don't know how to do.

Comment: Checkout docker images.

Comment: what are docker images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` to generate a list of the packages (`pip freeze`) you have installed in your venv (`-l` for local) and output it (`>`) to the file `requirements.txt`. Make sure this file is placed in the root folder of your project.

Users of your project can then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all packages on the list, at the same version they were at when you generated the list.

Answer (score 0):

@jomh are those python packages that you added? If they are, you can create a `setup.py` file to allow other people installing this project to install the same deps - see this official document - https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html.
If you want to be more advanced - you can use the `poetry` package to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, each machine that runs the project will need to have the same setup. New virtual environment and install the same packages.