# How do I make a github project automatically install my python packages when downloaded?

Tags: python, github

I'm new to using Github and I've made a website with flask that I would like to share on Github. However, when other people install it they will have to use "pip install" and install all the packages needed to use the project, which they will have to do several times while also needing to know the correct versions to install. How do people conventionally fix this issue? I apologize, since I've tried searching for the solution but I don't know what to search.

I've tried to include all the packages and their versions in a read.md file but it is hard to format so that it's all legible.

Comment: Use a `requirements.txt` and have instructions to initialize a python env from that. (or use poetry etc)

Comment: Whatever method you use to assemble your code into an installable package, it certainly has some way to specify all of the other modules it depends on.  What method are you using?

Comment: I have one folder that contains all my files. I'm not sure about whether or not that is a package. Do I need to make it a package?

Comment: If you expect it to be installable with `pip`, you do need to assemble it into a package.

Answer (score -1):

Create a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (virtual environment) for your project, then re-install each package you need inside of the venv. That way, only the packages you absolutely need will be available.

Then use the command `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` to generate a list of the packages (`pip freeze`) you have installed in your venv (`-l` for local) and output it (`>`) to the file `requirements.txt`. Make sure this file is placed in the root folder of your project.

Users of your project can then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all packages on the list, at the same version they were at when you generated the list. You can make a note of this in the project's README.

Comment: Don't copy [answers from other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129716/843953)  (even if it's your own answer). Flag this one as a duplicate if another question's answer also answers this one

Comment: @pho My bad, felt it was a bit different enough to warrant a slightly different answer. Thanks for the heads-up.